# Unique jQuery dialog for each php loop instance, inside sub tabs

Tags: php, jquery, loops, dialog

I've made a mess. :) I'm brand spankin new to jQuery. Extensive experience with PHP. pretty sure I've downloaded 1/4 of the internet in temp files trying to find clues to help, bought over $100 in books. please help me learn this!

Here's the situation. I'm working on a page where information can be edited. This information is sorted on a few different levels. We have Rooms and Items. Items can be many different items within a Room. These items are gathered, then looped into their appropriate tab, which is a Room. The tabs, tables, rows, etc are all handled within these loops. Furthermore, I'm trying to setup jquery to open a dialogue box to edit the items listed within a room. This dialog box will eventually have the UI sortable plugin to organize the data.

The loops work great, dialog boxes work, even the sortable features. However, since each tab should have its own unique dialog, I know I need to have a unique identifier for each  object, which I can easily accomplish in my loops, but can't figure out how to get jQuery to recognize it.

So, when you click 'edit' a dialog box appears for each dialog object.

What's the best way to handle this? a jQuery loop?

(I left out buncha stuff that didn't seem relavent. Sorry if the syntax is messy, I clean up after it works. :P )

**PHP/HTML**

```
    $count = count( $tpl['template'] );

for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
{
    foreach( $tpl['template'][$i] as $k => $v )
    {
        if( is_int($k) )
        {
            unset( $tpl['template'][$i][$k] );
        }
    }
}

$temprooms = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++ )
{
    foreach( $tpl['template'][$i] as $k => $v )
    {
        if( $k == "room_name" )
        {
            if( ! in_array($v, $temprooms, true ) )
            {
                $temprooms[] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
}
$rooms = array();
foreach( $temprooms as $k => $v )
{
    $rooms[$k+1] = $v;
}
?>
<div id="nested-tabs">
        <ul>
<?
foreach( $rooms as $k => $v )
{
?> <li><a href="#<?echo $v; ?>"><?echo $v; ?></a></li>
<?
}
?>
</ul>

<?php
krumo( $tpl['template'] );

foreach( $rooms as $these => $those )
{
?>
        <div id="<?php echo $those; ?>">
          <table class="ebc-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <table class="ebc-table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="sub">Component</th>
                      <th class="sub">U/M</th>
                      <th class="sub">Clean</th>
                      <th class="sub">Repair</th>
                      <th class="sub">Replace</th>
                      <th class="sub">Upgrade</th>
                    </tr>
<?
    foreach( $tpl['template'] as $k => $v )
    {
        foreach( $tpl['template'][$k] as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $key == "room_name" )
            {
                if( $key != $those )
                {
                    $roomname = $value;
                }
            }
            else{
                if( $v['room_name'] == $those )
                {
                    if( $key == "item_name" )
                    {
?>                  <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
<?
                    }
                    if( $key == "um" )
                    {
?>                  <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
<?
                    }
                    if( $key == "GROUP_CONCAT(IC.amt)" )
                    {
                        $prices = explode( ",", $value );
                        foreach( $prices as $index => $price )
                        {
?>                      <td><?php echo $price; ?> </td>
<?                  }
?>                  </tr> <?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

                      </thead>
                </table>
              </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <label class="title">&nbsp;</label>
                        <a href="#" class="room-edit" >Edit</a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
         </div>


    <div class="edit-dialog" title="Edit Room">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%">
                    <p>
                        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="add-all">&lt; Add All</a>
                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="remove-all">Remove All &gt;</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <br />
                            <a href="#" class="reset">Reset</a>
                        </p>
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td width="40%">
                    <p>
                        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
                            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<?
}
?>
```

Here's the script snippet I'm trying to work with:

```
if( $ ('div.edit-dialog').length > 0){
    $( 'div.edit-dialog' ).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        height: 500,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        position:['middle','middle'],
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }
    });

    $( 'a.room-edit').click(function() {
        $( 'div.edit-dialog' ).dialog( "open" );
        });

    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        dropOnEmpty: true
    }).disableSelection();

    $("a.add-all").click(function() {
        $("#sortable2 li").appendTo("#sortable1");
    });
    $("a.remove-all").click(function() {
        $("#sortable1 li").appendTo("#sortable2");
    });
    $("a.reset").click(function(resetall) {
        $('#sortable1').html('');
        $('#sortable2').html('');
        $('#sortable1').html(reset1);
        $('#sortable2').html(reset2);
    });

    var reset1 = $('#sortable1').html();
    var reset2 = $('#sortable2').html();

}
```

Let me know if you need anymore info.

Thanks so much!

Comment: why do you have the if conditional on the length? and is that all wrapped in a document ready somehow?

Comment: The conditional length is not relevant. Yes, all wrapped nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use HTML5 data- attributes to achieve your goal:

So your a.room-edit nodes could be like:

```
<a href="#" class="room-edit" data-roomID="room_12345">Edit</a>
```

And your click function could be like:

```
$( 'a.room-edit').click(function() {
    var roomID = $(this).attr('data-roomID');

    // do something spectacular
});
```

Comment: Good solution. I found that earlier too, and wanted to use it. Got attr() empty error. Must I have a minimum version of jquery to make sure this works?

Comment: I don't think so, as I believe .attr() has been part of the framework for a long time. Good luck finding what may be the cause of the empty values

Comment: I'm on 1.4.4

Should I be ok?

Comment: 1.4.4 use `.data('roomID')` perhaps?